# Avoiding explicit generic type c#

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

Say I have a generic `class` that has a constraint where `T` must implement `IWatchable<TKey>`, is there any way of then using the `Watcher` without having to explicitly declare the `TKey` type, considering that `T` would be providing that anyway?

```
public class Watcher<T, TKey> where T : IWatchable<TKey>
{
}

public interface IWatchable<TKey>
{
    TKey Key { get; }
}
```

If I then want to use the `Watcher` `class` I have to declare the `TKey` as the second type regardless.

```
var watcher = new Watcher<BeingWatched, int>();

public class BeingWatched : IWatchable<int> { ... }
```

Or

```
var watcher = new Watcher<AlsoBeingWatched<Guid>, Guid>();

public class AlsoBeingWatched<TKey> : IWatchable<TKey> { ... }
```

Comment: Consider that the type system will allow a type to implement a generic interface *multiple* times (with different type arguments).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So if `BeingWatched` implemented `IWatchable<int>` and `IWatchable<Guid>` then the `Watcher` wouldn't know which implementation to use within `BeingWatched`? Which is why it needs to explicit.

Comment: The `where` clause is only used for constraint *checking* not for type resolving... However, do you even need to know `T` on the `Watcher`? Maybe it is enough to register a watcher as `public class Watcher<TKey>` and work with `IWatchable` instead of the concrete type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you essentially want the compiler to infer one of the generic types from the other. You can get some distance towards this by using a static generic construction method but you would have to compromise and make Watcher<T, TKey> implement an interface with only a single generic type param. I'll try to illustrate below and you can decide whether it's worth making the compromise.

Here's your existing Watcher class..

```
public class Watcher<T, TKey> : IWatcher<TKey> where T : IWatchable<TKey>
{
    public Watcher(IWatchable<TKey> target) { }
}
```

and here's the interface that it will need to implement:

```
public interface IWatcher<TKey> { }
```

Now we'll need a non-generic static Watcher class that will contain a generic method that will require only one type param:

```
public static class Watcher
{
    public static IWatcher<TKey> For<TKey>(IWatchable<TKey> target)
    {
        return new Watcher<IWatchable<TKey>, TKey>(target);
    }
}
```

Note that the type signature has IWatcher<TKey> as the return type even though it's constructing a Watcher<IWatchable<TKey>, TKey>. This trick is what allows us to specify just one type param.

The next trick is to rely upon C#'s type inference so that we don't have to specify the "TKey" type when calling the "For" method. If we have take the class:

```
public class BeingWatched : IWatchable<int>
{
    public BeingWatched(int key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public int Key { get; }
}
```

then we can get a watcher for an instance of this with the following code:

```
var watcher = Watcher.For(new BeingWatched(123));
```

Type inference saves us from having to explicitly write

```
var watcher = Watcher.For<int>(new BeingWatched(123));
```

This works so long as there is no ambiguity. If you have a class

```
public class AlsoBeingWatched : IWatchable<int>, IWatchable<Guid>
{
    private readonly int _numberKey;
    private readonly Guid _guidKey;
    public AlsoBeingWatched(int numberKey, Guid guidKey)
    {
        _numberKey = numberKey;
        _guidKey = guidKey;
    }

    int IWatchable<int>.Key { get { return _numberKey; } }

    Guid IWatchable<Guid>.Key { get { return _guidKey; } }
}
```

then

```
var watcher = Watcher.For(new AlsoBeingWatched(123, Guid.NewGuid()));
```

won't compile, you will get the error

```
The type arguments for method 'Watcher.For<TKey>(IWatchable<TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
```

You will have to explicitly specify either

```
var watcher = Watcher.For<int>(new AlsoBeingWatched(123, Guid.NewGuid()));
```

or

```
var watcher = Watcher.For<Guid>(new AlsoBeingWatched(123, Guid.NewGuid()));
```

This approach might not be quite what you were asking for (or what you were hoping for, perhaps) but I think that it's the best way to avoid having to explicitly specify types for many of the common cases.

Comment: Interesting workaround, it definitely seems like overkill, but now I understand why the type must be explicity declared. Thanks though!